# Maximum range of projectile fired at given force and elevation

Tags: physics, projectile-physics

I've gone over this again and again, and my result is obviously wrong when viewed in-action. Here's the initial formula I converted (first one):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile

and here's my C# code:

```
float CalculateMaximumRange() {
    float g = Physics.gravity.y;
    float y = origin.position.y;
    float v = projectileSpeed;
    float a = 45;

    float vSin = v * Mathf.Sin(a);
    float vCos = v * Mathf.Cos(a);

    float sqrt = Mathf.Sqrt(vSin * vSin + 2 * g * y);

    return Mathf.Abs((vCos / g) * (vSin + sqrt));
}
```

Does anyone see what I did wrong?

Comment: Two things, this is in 2d? And does your Trig functions require radians instead of degrees?

Comment: Not only that but your variable names could be better. vSin should probably be v_x to represent that it it the X component of v for example.

Comment: What is the MathF class anyway, I' used to seeing Math and MathHelper (float math), not MathF.

Comment: @Roy T, it's Unity's floating point math helper class.

Comment: Do you have unit tests where you verify the range given a bunch of different inputs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use degrees instead of radians.

45 degrees is Pi/4 radians ~= 0.785398.

The `y` in your formula should be the object's distance above the ground when it is released. Is the ground 0? If the ground is not at y=0, then y should be:

`y = origin.Position.y + groundHeight`

Finally, are you sure that this formula is giving you what you want? This formula gives the horizontal distance of the object's travel only -- not the distance of the object along the path (which is longer or equal to the horizontal travel).

Based on your response, it sounds like you're actually looking for the maximum possible distance that can be achieved.

To find the angle that gives the maximum possible distance, use this (using your variable names):

```
 a = arccos(sqrt((2*g*y + v*v)/(2*g*y + 2*v*v)))
```

Now you can plug `a` into the equation you already have to find what the distance is at that angle.

Now you have both the angle that produces the maximum distance, and the maximum possible distance itself!

For example:
g = 30, y = 3.85, v = 35, gives:

[Wolfram Alpha computation.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccos%28sqrt%28%282%2a30%2a3.85%20%2b%2035%2a35%29/%282%2a30%2a3.85%20%2b%202%2a35%2a35%29%29%29)

a = 0.7422637 radians = 42.53 degrees.

[Then plugging a into your original formula gives range = 44.517.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%2835%2acos%280.7422637%29%29/30%29%20%2a%20%2835%2asin%280.7422637%29%20%20%2b%20sqrt%28%2835%2asin%280.7422637%29%2a35%2asin%280.7422637%29%29%20%2b%202%2a30%2a3.85%29%29)

Comment: "This formula gives the horizontal distance of the object's travel only" -- CalculateMaximumRange looks just right.

Comment: Judging by "MathF", Joren is using Unity. In Unity MathF.Sin and MathF.Cos indeed work with degrees, not radians.

Comment: Joren should definitely check his constants (g) and units (g, v, y, a, result)

Comment: @Nevermind: Mathf.Sin appears to use radians: 

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sin.html

Comment: WTF, I could've sworn it uses degrees. OK, I was wrong, sorry.

Comment: I checked my variable values and these were my results ( tried both radians and degrees for the angle ).

g: -30 y: 3.854626 v: 35 a: 45
range: 33.94
g: -30 y: 3.854626 v: 35 a: 0.7853982
range: 36.5239

Nothing looks amiss. The range value is definitely wrong because if I manually set the range it still finds a solution angle given that elevation and velocity.

Comment: The actual range seems closer to ~50ish by manually returning that range value.

Comment: Those numbers make sense to me. The first set launches the projectile at 58.3 degrees upward, the other at 45 degrees upward. The 45 degree angle produced a longer range.
What do you meant it found a solution angle? What's "it"?

Comment: @Joren: That's because 45 degrees is not the optimal angle to fire the projectile at when you are not launching it from the ground (y=0 in your case).

Comment: @Joren: are you trying to find the maximum range of the projectile (i.e. what angle to fire it at to make it go furthest), or are you trying to find out how far it will go given an angle to fire it at?

Comment: @Joren: I edited my answer to provide you with the method for finding maximum distance.

Comment: @Krom: Turns out it's not just right :)

Comment: I was trying to find the maximum distance it could fire, which I thought meant a 45 degree angle. I see now that being elevated changes the optimum angle. I'll try your revised formula once I get off work. Thanks. :)

Comment: As you get higher and higher off the ground, the angle decreases. At infinite height, the ideal angle to fire the projectile is 0.

Comment: Just tried it and the returned range is roughly the same. The optimum angle returned is 48 degrees, which isn't nearly enough to make up for the ~40% shortfall.

Comment: That's because you entered -30 for gravity, which would mean that gravity is pointing up, and the floor is above you. Use 30 for gravity instead, and the result will be 42.53 degrees.

Comment: Ok it actually is working, it just didn't look like it because I was choosing the high angled firing solution.